# Python xml.dom.minidom - Please don't escape my Strings

Tags: xml, python-3.x, minidom

I am using the [minidom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) module to create XML Documents from my data.

At the moment I'm struggling to find some pythonic way to prevent minidom from escaping my Strings I put in there..

Cause of all evil is the `_write_data` method (on line 302 in the module):

```py
def _write_data(writer, data):
    "Writes datachars to writer."
    if data:
        data = data.replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;"). \
                    replace("\"", "&quot;").replace(">", "&gt;")
        writer.write(data)
```

All I want is the `data` without those `replace`ments.

---

I found some way to prevent this by monkeypathing two functions:

- `writexml` of the parent node
- and within that patch:

  - `_write_data`

I've prepared some example:

```py
from xml.dom import minidom

SNOWMAN = '&#x2603;&#xfe0e;'

imp = minidom.getDOMImplementation()
dom = imp.createDocument(None, 'root', None)
root = dom.documentElement

evil = dom.createElement('evil')
root.appendChild(evil)
# this does unwanted double escaping:
evil.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(SNOWMAN))

# now for something completely different ...
# this is some way to fix this:
good = dom.createElement('good')
root.appendChild(good)

# - store original ``writexml`` and ``_write_data``
original_writexml = good.writexml
original_write_data = minidom._write_data


def fake_writexml(writer, indent, addindent, newl):
    def fake_writedata(writer, data):
        if data:
            writer.write(data)

    # - overwrite ``_write_data``
    minidom._write_data = fake_writedata

    # - call original ``writexml``
    # -> which itself calls the now patched ``_write_data``
    original_writexml(writer, indent, addindent, newl)

    # - reset ``_write_data`` again
    minidom._write_data = original_write_data

# - overwrite ``writexml``
good.writexml = fake_writexml

# - do stuff
good.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(SNOWMAN))

# -> yay, it works!
print(dom.toprettyxml(indent=' '))

# - reset ``writexml`` again
good.writexml = original_writexml
# -> returns trash again..
print(dom.toprettyxml(indent=' '))
```

It will produce this output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
 <evil>&amp;#x2603;&amp;#xfe0e;</evil>
 <good>&#x2603;&#xfe0e;</good>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
 <evil>&amp;#x2603;&amp;#xfe0e;</evil>
 <good>&amp;#x2603;&amp;#xfe0e;</good>
</root>
```

Personally I don't think this is good code, as it messes around with the internals of `minidom`, and you have to be careful not to make any mistakes.

Please show me the most pythonic solution to that problem you can come up with - so I can finally enjoy the Snowmans ;-)

☃︎

Answer (score 1):

Thinking further about my problem here, I had one idea:

Isn't it possible to define a new type of Node?

Indeed - it is!

```
from xml.dom import minidom

SNOWMAN = '&#x2603;&#xfe0e;'

imp = minidom.getDOMImplementation()
dom = imp.createDocument(None, 'root', None)
```

So, I define my own Node there:

```
class RawText(minidom.Text):
    def writexml(self, writer, indent='', addindent='', newl=''):
        '''
        patching minidom.Text.writexml:1087
        the original calls minidom._write_data:302
        below is a combined version of both, but without the '&' replacements and so on..
        '''
        if self.data:
            writer.write('{}{}{}'.format(indent, self.data, newl))
```

After that I write some helper function for the original `minidom.Document` to create new Nodes of my own type.

```
def createRawTextNode(data):
    '''
    helper function for minidom.Document:1519 to create Nodes of RawText
    see minidom.Document.createTextNode:1656
    '''
    if not isinstance(data, str):
        raise TypeError('node contents must be a string')
    r = RawText()
    r.data = data
    r.ownerDocument = dom  # there is no self
    return r

# ... and attach the helper function
dom.createRawTextNode = createRawTextNode
```

And then, continue as if nothing happened:

```
root = dom.documentElement

evil = dom.createElement('evil')
root.appendChild(evil)
evil.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(SNOWMAN))

good = dom.createElement('good')
root.appendChild(good)
# use helper function to create Nodes of RawText
good.appendChild(dom.createRawTextNode(SNOWMAN))

# yay, works! |o_0|
print(dom.toprettyxml(indent=' '))
```

Finally it does what I want!

Both escaped and unescaped Strings in my output without trouble.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
 <evil>&amp;#x2603;&amp;#xfe0e;</evil>
 <good>&#x2603;&#xfe0e;</good>
</root>
```